# Merge two audio sources with avconv

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, avconv

I am trying to record my desktop with `avconv`. It's working pretty good. My only problem is that one of my audio channels is too slow / downpitched and so has an offset.

Adding an offset to the stream with `-itsoffset 4.4` fixes the offset but not the wrong speed / pitch.

The command I use is:

```
avconv -f pulse -ac 2 -ar 128000 -i alsa_output.usb-Logitech_Logitech_G930_Headset-00-Headset.analog-stereo.monitor -f pulse -ac 2 -ar 128000 -i alsa_input.usb-Logitech_Logitech_G930_Headset-00-Headset.analog-mono -filter_complex amix -video_size 1680x1050 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -c:v libx264 -qp 0 -skip_frame none -preset ultrafast -r 25 -profile:v high444 capture.mkv
```

The audio stream with the problem is ***alsa_output.usb-Logitech_Logitech_G930_Headset-00-Headset.analog-stereo.monitor*** so it's the mirror of my computers sound. The input from my microphone is working just fine.

What am I doing wrong here? The audio output sounds normal through my headset.